# i want to set dynamically variables in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 box and applying this function but problem is when click on first box tab then action all boxes. i want to only one box response on first box tab.
How is possible? and sorry for English mistake [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGNww.png)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var tabNum = $(this).index();
        var nthChild = tabNum+1;
        $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#tab .li.active").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab .li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
    }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Note:

Just noticed, seems you are having ***duplicate IDs*** for `tabs`. Better to change it to class or give unique ID to each `#tab`.

---

You have a `.` before `li` which is a tag and that changes it to class selector:

```
$("#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
$("#tab li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
```

or you can use `.eq()` method:

```
$("#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
$("#tab li").eq(nthChild).addClass("active");
```

Comment: `      $(".tabid .li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".tabid .li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");` not working :(

Comment: i want to change these both line `$(".tabid .li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".tabid .li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");` with different class ".tabid123 .li.active" and  ".tabid456 .li.active"  ... so on,  when a mysql array loop executed and click on tab show effect only current box no all. please help me